# USB 3.1 Type C port to display output

Tags: display, hdmi, gpu, vga

I have a Asus ROG GL553VD laptop that has a USB 3.1 TYPE C port. Is it possible to make this port output data from the GPU? So that I have another display that I can use in conjunction with the laptop's screen. I know there are some adapters for Type C to HDMI conversion, perhaps I can use them for this purpose?

Comment: No; Your laptop doesn't support connecting your monitor to its USB port.

Comment: "The USB 3.1 Type-C port must support DP Alternate (Alt) Mode or DisplayPort and you can normally see the DP-logo next to the port if this is the case." - from Random Microsoft Support thread. If the port has the logo then it will work, otherwise, it won't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

USB-C is a connector type.

It might support one or more of the following protocols:

- USB 2
- USB 3
- USB 3.1
- Thunderbolt
- Display Port

I believe that both the cable AND the connector/device must support the desired protocols.

As Ramhound mentioned, your device does not support the DisplayPort or Thunderbolt modes and so is basically only a USB port.

For more information I recommend you read http://blog.fosketts.net/2016/10/29/total-nightmare-usb-c-thunderbolt-3/